# JAVAC ERROR-'javac' is not recognized internal or external command: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.compile

Tags: maven, pom.xml

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project : Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.

I am getting this error and below is the Plugin i have in pom.xml of my project

<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>${websphere_jdk_5}</executable>
                    <meminitial>256m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>   
      </plugins>
```

JAVAC is not recognizing as internal or external command i have jdk8 will it work and executable tag for webshere does mean i need to add websphere application server to run but to build only jdk i have added and trying to build the project

Comment: First `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` you have to install a Java compiler means a JDK... also I strongly recommend to use more recent things because JDK 5 is ancient old as well as maven-compiler-plugin version... 2.0.2 ? ... If you use JDK 8 you should use more recent versions of plugins etc....

Comment: after adding latest version for plugin and jdk 8 it worked